# Complexity of subset sum solver algorithm

Tags: time-complexity

I made a subset sum problem but I am still confused about its complexity.
Please find the algorithm here:

http://www.vinaysofs.com/P=NP%20proved%20with%20Subset%20Sum%20Problem%20solution%20manuscript.pdf

Basically the essence is:

```
i = 0;
func1(i)
{
    if(func1(i + 1))
        return true;
    else
        func1(i + 2, with few modifications in other arguments);
}
```

Here, `i` is index of an element in an integer set like {1,1,1,1,1,1}.

Worst case for above algorithm comes when all elements are 1 and we need a sum which is 1 more than the total sum of all elements.

I want to know the complexity of this algorithm as someone told me it is non polynomial(Exponential time - `2^n`. If it is polynomial then it would be a big achievement.

In my view also it is not polynomial as `T(n)=2T(n-1)+6` but that is in worst case that is every time the 1st recursive call fails.

Please help..

Thanks
Vinay

Comment: If you have to come to StackOverflow to ask whether you've solved one of the Clay Institute's Millennium prizes, I am going to going out on a limb and claim you haven't.

Comment: http://www.cse.unr.edu/~bebis/CS477/Lect/Recurrences.ppt . Here on slide 26 it says that algorithm is O(n(loga to base b + or - e) which is like polynomial but I read on someone else's question about T(n)=2T(n-1) having exponential complexity(2^n). Hence the confusion..

Comment: That formula on the slide is not the time complexity, it's a condition, and it doesn't apply because you don't have a T(n/b) term. Your algorithm needs to efficiently deal with every case including where no subset sum is found, but it doesn't and would take much more work to do so.